# Xcode produces warnings 'Implicit declaration of function N is invalid in C99' for C functions imported in .pch file

Tags: xcode

Unlike the behavior described in this SO topic: [xCode 4.4 does not get all the .pch file headers imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840622/xcode-4-4-does-not-get-all-the-pch-file-headers-imports), my project does builds successfully, but anyway I see these annoying yellow highlights Xcode gives me in its editors.

How can I teach Xcode to pick up .pch-file headers imports or is this a buggy behavior?

Comment: Xcode? Certainly not. At most the compiler. What have you ([{tried}]) imported? Which functions it is complaining about?

Comment: If you see the yellow sing only (but no actual warning during the compiler run), it might be sufficient to rebuild Xcode's symbol database.

Comment: Suddenly I get this. I explicitly put the stuff in another .h file and included that, but that didn't work either. Cleaned, recompiled, restarted. Nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very strange, but after restarting Xcode and cleaning build folder (just one more command+alt+shift+K in response to @Matthias comment) warnings have gone.

I say 'strange' because I did see them for about a week (after I had extracted a couple of small utility C functions as a Cocoa Pod and had begun importing them in my .pch-file).

I will provide more details here, if I ever see this behavior again and notice any details about how it can occur.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by adding #include <arpa/inet.h> in .pch file of my xcode project